# find max values of columns in excel sheets and highlight it by making it bold - openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, python-3.6

I have started to learn openpyxl. I have learnt how to find max values, make values of cell bold, apply formulas etc. Now, I am facing a problem. I have excel file which contains 10 work sheets. In these 10 sheets, first I have to retrieve 4 sheets, then I have to find maximum value in each column and make it bold. I have written a code but it doesn't work perfectly - Some times work correctly, sometimes not.

[Here is the Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwBntjDiENh5cldFSmw1S1c5enc) to sample input and outpout files.

Here is the code:

```
import os
from openpyxl.formatting import Rule
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill, Border
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
import shutil
shutil.copy('../test.xlsx', 'test.xlsx')

def bold_max_columnValue(file):
  wb =  load_workbook(file)
  for ws in wb.worksheets:

    if ws.title in ['Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall', 'F1-Measure']:

      dxf = DifferentialStyle(font=Font(bold=True))
      range_cell = 'C5:C10'
      rule = Rule(type='cellIs', dxf=dxf, formula=["=MAX("+ range_cell +")"])
      ws.conditional_formatting.add(range_cell, rule)

      range_cell = 'D5:D10'
      rule = Rule(type='cellIs', dxf=dxf, formula=["=MAX("+ range_cell +")"])
      ws.conditional_formatting.add(range_cell, rule)

      range_cell = 'E5:E10'
      rule = Rule(type='cellIs', dxf=dxf, formula=["=MAX("+ range_cell +")"])
      ws.conditional_formatting.add(range_cell, rule)

      range_cell = 'F5:F10'
      rule = Rule(type='cellIs', dxf=dxf, formula=["=MAX("+ range_cell +")"])
      ws.conditional_formatting.add(range_cell, rule)

      range_cell = 'G5:G10'
      rule = Rule(type='cellIs', dxf=dxf, formula=["=MAX("+ range_cell +")"])
      ws.conditional_formatting.add(range_cell, rule)

      range_cell = 'H5:H10'
      rule = Rule(type='cellIs', dxf=dxf, formula=["=MAX("+ range_cell +")"])
      ws.conditional_formatting.add(range_cell, rule)
  wb.save('output-test.xlsx')


def iterate_files():
  for file in os.listdir('.'):
    stop = file.split('.')
    if stop[-1] in ['xlsx']:
      print(file)
      bold_max_columnValue(file)

iterate_files()
print('Script Completed')
```

I have studied [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/formatting.html) documentation but it didn't help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide more information about what doesn't work. As you're using conditional formatting evaluation of any rules is handled by Excel. You can, however, start by simplifying your code which has lots of repetitive steps.

Comment: There are two problems. 
1. It always select and bold the last row of the table. 
2. Sometimes, it select more than one values.  
3. Sometimes, it work correctly (strangely)  
Here is the [link] for snapshots of input/output file   (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwBntjDiENh5X2VPTmlibHNoeVk)  
(I've intention to remove repetitive steps later, when code start working somewhat acceptable) 
Thanks @CharlieClark

Answer (score 0):

You're really asking about how Excel evaluates the conditional formatting which I can't help you with. It might be better to create a template from Excel and reverse engineer the formatting from that. The rules for conditional formatting are often counter-intuitive.

If you only want to highlight the cell with the highest value then you can use the Top10 rule and just set it to include one value:

`<cfRule type="top10" dxfId="1" priority="1" percent="1" rank="1">`

Otherwise I think you may need to use absolute coordinates `$A$1:$A$5` because conditional formats default to using relative coordinates.